Keyframe Animation in Loop
Keyframe animation in infinity loop, try to fix can anyone fix this?
I've tried many different combinations of animation-direction but to no avail.
The below works but when it gets to the second animation, it keeps repeating only that animation and does not loop.


body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:lato,sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center; 
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/436544/wyperfeld.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center top;
  color:white;
}

h1 {
  color:transparent; /* text shadow does all the work */
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  margin-top:-.5em;
  margin-left:-.5em;
  animation: cinematicInOut 5s ease-in-out 2s;
}
h1:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:7s;
}
h1:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay:12s;
}


@keyframes cinematicInOut {
  0% {
    text-shadow:0 0 1em white;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-.5em;
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow:0 0 0 white;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow:0 0 0 white;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow:0 0 1em white;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
<h1>Bark Side Down presents</h1>
<h1>A cinematic CSS animation</h1>
<h1>Using text-shadow</h1>




It's a bit challenging but it's all about timing, If you make all elements have the same duration it can work easily.
I modified the timing for the keyframes so each h1 is visible between 25% to 45%, to make it work, the animation duration must follow the equation:
duration = first element duration time(implicit) + last element delay time
So if you add/remove another heading, you will increase/decrease the animation duration accordingly.
In the example below, each h1 will appear for 4 seconds, the duration equation is 12 = 4 + 8


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/436544/wyperfeld.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: transparent; /* text shadow does all the work */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  margin-left: -.5em;
  animation: cinematicInOut 12s ease-in-out infinite;
}

h1:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
h1:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
h1:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes cinematicInOut {
  0%, 20%, 100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em white;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -.5em;
  }
  25%, 45% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  50%, 70% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em white;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
<h1>Bark Side Down presents</h1>
<h1>A cinematic CSS animation</h1>
<h1>Using text-shadow</h1>



